# Estilo de programación matriz reflexiva

Tags: c++, loops, matrices

Tengo una duda con las matrices reflexivas, quiero aclarar una cosa para los que quieran editar esta pregunta: esta pregunta es de un código COMPILADO Y QUE FUNCIONA BIEN, solo es una duda respecto al estilo de programación.

Este es el enunciado del ejercicio:

> Impleméntese  el  método  bool    matrix_t::is_reflexive(void),  el  cual    devuelve    verdadero   si  la
>   relación  descrita    en  la  matriz   es  reflexiva,  o   falso   en 
>   caso  contrario.   Es  decir,  devuelve verdadero  si  todo    elemento   de A.   Está relacionado     consigo    mismo.

Atención, este es el código del ejercicio resuelto:

```
bool is_reflexive(void)
{ bool is_ref = true;
  int  i      = 1;

  while ((is_ref == true) && (i <= get_m())) {
    if (get(i,i) != 1)
      is_ref = false;
    i++;
  }
  return is_ref;
}
```

LA MANERA EN QUE LO HICE YO:

```
bool matrix_t<int>::is_reflexive(void){

for (int i=1; i<m_ && !encontrado;i++){
  for(int j=1;j<n_ && !encontrado;j++){

    if(get(i,i) !=0){
       encontrado = true;
    }
  }
}
return encontrado;

}
```

Mi pregunta es: recorrer las filas y las columnas en vez de filas solo hace ineficiente mi código? inicializar encontrado a false lo hace ineficiente también?

No utilicé la función `get_m()` porque estoy en la misma clase, ellos la utilizaron,pero me funcionó, eso está bien?

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te han explicado, una matriz reflexiva es aquella en la que los elementos de la diagonal principal son 1.

Esto implica, aparte de lo comentado por [@Solrac](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91172/463):

- Que la matriz debe ser cuadrada.
- Solo se admite el 1 como valor válido en dicha diagonal.

Posible implementación:

```
bool matrix_t<int>::is_reflexive()
{
    bool esReflexiva = (get_m() == get_n());
    for (int i = 0; (i < get_m()) && (esReflexiva); i++) {
      esReflexiva = (get(i,i) == 1);
    }
    return esReflexiva;
}
```

Y ahora las preguntas:

> recorrer las filas y las columnas en vez de filas solo hace ineficiente mi código?

Si tienes un bucle tal que:

```
for (int i=1; i<m_ && !encontrado;i++){
  for(int j=1;j<n_ && !encontrado;j++){

    if(get(i,i) !=0){
       encontrado = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Estás realizando `m_*n_` iteraciones, mientras que si el bucle queda así:

```
for (int i = 0; (i < m_) && (esReflexiva); i++) {
  esReflexiva = (get(i,i) == 1);
}
```

Con m_ iteraciones consigues el mismo resultado. Parece obvio pensar que `m_` iteraciones son muchas menos que `m_*n_`, ¿no? El resultado es que, efectivamente, tu algoritmo será menos eficiente... aunque dicho sea de paso, para lo que se propone en el ejercicio no notarás alguna diferencia.

Lo que sí sería más acertado decir es que tu solución no es correcta aunque el resultado fuese bueno y el motivo es que estás trabajando con variables que no tienen utilidad alguna (`j` en el segundo bucle). Esa parte no solo no aporta ningún valor al algoritmo sino que complica su legibilidad.

> inicializar encontrado a false lo hace ineficiente también?

Inicializar `encontrado` a `false` no es que lo haga ineficiente... impide que el programa funcione correctamente.

Si el objetivo del algoritmo es garantizar que la matriz principal es 1 entonces el programa deberá fallar si se encuentra un número diferente.

Lo que tu estás haciendo es asumir que la matriz no va a ser adyacente y, al encontrarte un 1, decidir que sí va a ser adyacente. Dicho con un ejemplo, tu algoritmo detecta como matriz adyacente las siguientes:

```
0 0 0    1 0 0    4 0 0
0 8 0    0 0 0    0 1 0
0 0 1    0 0 0    0 0 7
```

Answer (score 1):

La relación descrita en una matriz es reflexiva si la diagonal principal de la matriz contiene sólo 1's (unos). Por lo tanto lo que se debe de recorrer es la diagonal principal.

En tu código:

- el segundo *for* esta de más.
- el usar la variable`m_` directamente esta bien, ya que la función pertenece a la clase.
- inicializar la variable `encontrado` no hace ineficiente el código.
- la lógica que usas para verificar la relación reflexiva esta errada, debido a que estás verificando que al menos exista un 1 (uno), y lo que tienes que verificar es que todos sean unos o lo que es igual adecir que no existan 0's (ceros)

Intenta esto:

```
bool matrix_t<int>::is_reflexive(void)
{
    esReflexiva = true;
    for (int i = 0; (i < m_) && (esReflexiva); i++) {
        if (get(i,i) == 0) {
            esReflexiva = false;
        }
    }
    return esReflexiva;
}
```

NOTA: el inicio y la condición de final del indice `i` va a ser determinado de acuerdo a como esta almacenada tu matriz.